# return variable after for loop in a different class

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods

So i tried to create a for loop in a different class and wanted to get the last value of the loop outside to the main function. Problem is: x cannot be resolved...
I also want to have many values and a for loop in a different class. How do i fix this issue? Any help is very welcome. I thank you in advance.

```
public class Javaapp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Data a = new Data();
        int[] getData = a.returnData();

        a.for1();
        System.out.println(a.x); //x cannot be resolved or is not a field
        System.out.println(a.k);
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------
public class Data {
int k=1;
    public double for1() {
        int x = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x = x *x;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public class Javaapp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Data a = new Data();
        int[] getData = a.returnData();

        // a.for1();
        System.out.println(a.for1());
        System.out.println(a.k);
    }
}
```

Comment: it prints out x= 0.0 and k= 1. But i wanted x to multiply by itself and then give me the result. I can do it in one class but using a different class is something i cannot fix myself.

Comment: `for1 ()` returns zero. Because `x` overflows during the loop. `x` = 2, 4, 16, 256, 65536, 0, 0, 0, ...

Comment: YEES, thank you now it works. I didnt expect an overflow happening in Java...

Answer (score 0):

To access the loop value after the loop, you need to set the class property or capture the return value from the function.

Try this code:

```
public class Javaapp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Data a = new Data();
        int[] getData = a.returnData();

        a.for1();  // can also call:  int x = a.for1();
        System.out.println(a.x); //x cannot be resolved or is not a field
        System.out.println(a.k);
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------
public class Data {
    public int k=1;  // can access outside class
    public int x=0;
    public double for1() {
        int x = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x = x *x;
        }
        this.x = x; // set class property 
        return x;   // return value
    }
}
```

Comment: it just prints out x = 0 and k= 1 . But i wanted x to be multiplied by itself and then give me the result.